# C# serialize dictionary with custom comparator

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I try to serialize a dictionary with a custom comparator like:

```
new Dictionary<keyObj, valueObj>(customComparator);
```

Unfortunately, the only way to keep the custom comparator when deserializing is with the `[OnDeserialized()]` attribute. But this method requires that I set all the comparator manual.
Is the a way to automaticly (de)serialize the comparator property?

Edit:
I am using the `DataContractSerializer`.

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't in the question already, but in case you weren't aware, there are many serializers. For example: XmlSerializer built into .NET, BinaryFormatter built into .NET, System.Text.Json built into .NET, JSON.NET, etc. So what do you mean when you say "serializer"? And a **Comparer** (not Comparator) isn't data, so of course it isn't included in serialization.

Comment: You can't really serialise the comparer. Comparers are basically blocks of code, not data.

Comment: @LucaJung to make it easier to answer your question, please provide a [mre] that shows how you are currently de-/serializing the Dictionary. That way we don't have to write it from scratch and are more likely to get the same results you are reporting. As ProgrammingLlama hints, are you really interested in serializing it or is it enough to set the comparer while deserializing? Please describe your expected output.